# Is Rx.Subject a hot observable?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

The code

```
const a = new Rx.Subject().do(x => console.log('a'))
const b = a.mapTo(0)
const c = a.mapTo(1)
const d = Rx.Observable.merge(b, c)
d.subscribe(x => console.log('d'))
a.next(3)
```

And the output

```
a
d
a
d
```

Why does a got printed twice? Isn't Rx.Subject a hot observable?

Comment: In my application, a calls fetch and running a twice results in two http requests...

Answer (score 16):

The `Subject` itself is hot/shared.

**However:** Any(most!) operators that you append will create a new stream, with the previous stream(in this case the `Subject`) as source - the new stream, however, is (for most operators) not hot and will only be made hot by deriving a hot stream through appending a *hot operator* (like `share` or `publish` ect...)

So when you `share` your `do`, everything should work as expected.

```js
const a = new Rx.Subject().do(x => console.log('a')).share();
const b = a.mapTo(0);
const c = a.mapTo(1);
const d = Rx.Observable.merge(b, c)
d.subscribe(x => console.log('d'));
a.next(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm now using `.publishReplay(1).refCount()` for all my internal streams

Answer (score 12):

You need to understand cold/hot observable and subject.

A **cold Observable** is an Observable that re-executes its subscribe handler every time it's subscribed to:

```
const cold = new Observable(function subscribe(observer) {
  console.log('subscribed');
  observer.next(Math.random());
  observer.complete();
});
// > subscribed
// sub 1: 0.1231231231231
cold.subscribe((num) => console.log('sub 1:', num));
// > subscribed
// sub 2: 0.09805969045
cold.subscribe((num) => console.log('sub 2:', num));
```

A **hot Observable** is a source Observable (cold or otherwise) that has a Subject between the source and subscribers. When a hot Observable is subscribed to, the subscription is internally routed to the inner Subject transparently, and the Subject is subscribed to the source Observable. This ensures the source Observable only has one subscriber (the Subject), and the Subject shares the source's value with many Subscribers:

```
const cold = new Observable(function subscribe(observer) {
  console.log('subscribed');
  observer.next(Math.random());
  observer.complete();
});

const hot = cold.publish();
hot.subscribe((num) => console.log('sub 1:', num));
hot.subscribe((num) => console.log('sub 2:', num));
hot.connect(); // <-- this subscribes the inner Subject to the cold source
// > subscribed
// > sub 1: 0.249848935489
// > sub 2: 0.249848935489
```

You can make an Observable hot via multicast, which takes a function that returns a Subject to use when it's connected. There are also variants of multicast for convenience (such as publish) that create specific types of Subjects. `publish()` is a convenience method for `multicast(() => new Subject())`

In addition to `connect()`, which subscribes the inner Subject to the source and returns the underlying Subscription, you can call `refCount()`, which returns an Observable. When the Observable returned by `refCount()` is subscribed to once, it will automatically call `connect()` internally, and subsequent subscriptions won't reconnect. When all subscribers unsubscribe, `refCount` will automatically unsubscribe the inner Subject from the source. `share()` is a convenience method for `source.publish().refCount()`.

So, it will work,

```
const a = new Rx.Subject().do(x => console.log('a')).share();
const b = a.mapTo(0);
const c = a.mapTo(1);
const d = Rx.Observable.merge(b, c)
d.subscribe(x => console.log('d'));
a.next(3);
```